В чем причина тавтологии? Как правильно определить плеоназм и тавтологию?

Как определить тавтологию?

Из стихотворения: Ты не услышишь слов моих укор, Хоть всё украл, что было у меня.
Почему-то выделенные слова напрягают слух, хотя там нет ни плеоназма, ни тавтологии. Ведь это не родственные слова даже по этимологии. Будет ли здесь стилистическая погрешность и почему?
И если это так, то можно ли сказать, что в основе тавтологии лежит ЗВУКОВОЙ ПОВТОР (а не просто повтор однокоренных слов), который мы воспринимаем негативно или, напротив, позитивно (как средство выразительности?

Как соотносятся плеоназм и тавтология? Правильно считать, что общим понятием является речевая избыточность, в то время как тавтология и плеоназм — это частные случаи такой избыточности и определяются независимо?

Но есть мнение, что тавтология — вид плеоназма.  Дело в том, что сам термин пришел из древнегреческого языка и переводится как «излишество». Но тогда надо понимать два значения слова плеоназм, так не лучше ли рассматривать тавтологию (повтор однокоренных или одинаковых слов) и плеоназм (смысловую избыточность) отдельно?

Звуковой повтор фиксируется четко (остальные остатки), а смысловой повтор (последние остатки) зависит о контекста и контролируется по словарю. Другими словами, это более сложный анализ Эта мысль лишила его последних остатков разума, и он почувствовал себя таким беспомощным! Фрижель, Пленники подземного мира, 2017

ОСТАТОК, -тка; м. 1. Оставшаяся неиспользованной, неизрасходованной часть чего-л. ПОСЛЕДНИЙ, -яя, -ее. 2. Подходящий к концу, иссякающий.
Речевая избыточность

Мы часто слышим, что это "авторское", поэтому у авторов погрешности списываются и на авторское, и на собственные литературные приемы. На слух слова из вашей фразы несколько сливаются и, тем самым, теряются, на мой взгляд. Может быть, заменить "украл" на "отнял", если это возможно

Спасибо за ответ, но дело не в самой фразе. Мне интересно, это тавтология или нет? Ведь слова не однокоренные, а просто похожие.  Есть ли правило, которое тавтологией считает такие слова. И как тогда определить тавтологию?  Могу я сказать, что это любой звуковой повтор.  // А если все же тавтология, можно ли считать это художественным созвучием или все же не звучит?)  // Что касается стиха, то замена нежелательна. Там тема такая: вор, который украл; к тому же это перевод:  Although thou steal thee all my poverty)
